# Рефакторинг кода JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Делаю динамический поиск, т.е. добавляю и удаляю элементы (в таблице) на лету. Можно ли как-то сократить код? `data_parse` - ассоциативный массив, полученный из сервера.

```
let data_parse = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(JSON.parse(data));

$('#listDataEmployee').remove();
let el_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (let i = 0; i < data_parse.length; i++) {
    let tagTrDataEmployee = document.createElement('tr');

    let tagTd_id = document.createElement('td');
    tagTd_id.innerHTML = data_parse[i]['id'];
    tagTrDataEmployee.append(tagTd_id);

    let tagTd_email = document.createElement('td');
    tagTd_email.innerHTML = data_parse[i]['email'];
    tagTrDataEmployee.append(tagTd_email);

    let tagTd_fio = document.createElement('td');
    tagTd_fio.innerHTML = data_parse[i]['FIO'];
    tagTrDataEmployee.append(tagTd_fio);

    let tagTd_phone = document.createElement('td');
    tagTd_phone.innerHTML = data_parse[i]['phone'];
    tagTrDataEmployee.append(tagTd_phone);

    let tagTd_role = document.createElement('td');
    tagTd_role.innerHTML = data_parse[i]['role'];
    tagTrDataEmployee.append(tagTd_fio);

    el_tbody.append(tagTrDataEmployee);
}
$('.listNewDataEmployee').append(el_tbody);
```

Comment: я бы принял как верный ответ Qwertiy. Да, он содержит меньше пояснений, зато пригоден к использованию без понимания того что там творится (считай не надо помнить про потенциальную xss). Галку можно переставить =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полагаю, на самом деле ты хочешь что-то такое:

```js
var data = `[
  {"id": 1, "email": "first@mail.ru", "FIO":"First Firstov", "phone": "+7 (111) 111 11 11", "role": "admin"},
  {"id": 2, "email": "second@mail.ru", "FIO":"Second Secondov", "phone":"+7 (222) 222 22 22", "role": "user"},
  {"id": 3, "email": "xss@mail.ru", "FIO":"<img src='http://void' onerror='alert(1)'>", "phone":"+7 (333) 333 33 33", "role": "test"}
]`;

data = JSON.parse(data);

$('#listDataEmployee').replaceWith(
  data.map(d => $("<tr>").append([
    $("<td>").text(d.id),
    $("<td>").text(d.email),
    $("<td>").text(d.FIO),
    $("<td>").text(d.phone),
    $("<td>").text(d.role),
])));
```

```css
table, tr, td, th { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID
      <th>Email
      <th>FIO
      <th>Phone
      <th>Role
    </tr>
  <tbody id="listDataEmployee">
</table>
```

Comment: Зачем делаются вызовы `.html` - если просится `.append`?

Comment: И зачем разворачивать результат map в массив через три точки - если map уже возвращает массив?

Comment: в вопросе не написано про jquery , неизвестно во что он этот код развернет.

Comment: Ну и чисто стилистически, имена переменных "data" и "d" мне не оч нравятся даже в вырожденном коде очень ухудшает читаемость. Даже фейковые данные можно различать, ну там "row" вместо "d", "tableData" вместо "data"

Comment: @perfect, в вопросе jquery во всю используется, так что можно его использовать кмк)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я убрал `remove`, поэтому вместо `append` поставлен `html`. С разворачиванием действительно накосячил - я хотел сделать другое, но потерял `concat`. Но оно и так работает. Всё, теперь в сниппете.

Comment: @perfect, в коде из вопроса jQuery используется.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму , просто какой смысл от рефракторинга если будет много лишнего кода (ну например для поддержания IE)

Comment: @Qwertiy аа ну да просто на метки смотрел, я не прав

Comment: @PavelMayorov 1. В чём преимущества `replaceWith`? 2. А `append` в пустой элемент?

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. в семантике. html принимает строку, и какого фига туда вообще можно передать объект - загадка.

Comment: @perfect, тут цель рефакторинга не перформанс, а упрощение читаемости и показать что "еще можно так". Выкидывать везде jQuery и городить свои велосипеды - признак человека который пишет бэк, а во фронт посматривает постольку поскольку.  А метку я щас добавил =)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму ну как сказать я сейчас пишу в проекте с старым jquery и по мне так лучше писать на чистом js потому что я устал бороться с jquery багами.

Comment: @Qwertiy, btw из любопытства чисто, так как к вопросу не относится: Почему Вы th не закрываете? Чисто стилистическое предпочтение или какая-то неизвестная мне магия? (Понятно что можно, но непонятно зачем так)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму. выпендриться захотел, очевидно ж :-)

Comment: @perfect, в jquery исключительно мало багов. Дело в ручках тех кто писал. И это к чистому js тоже относится, увы. А выпиливание из проекта jQuery когда проект чуть вырастет, приведет к появлению кривого глючного велосипеда для работы с DOM, я такое уже видел.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму ну да я так то же это вижу. надо jquery обновить но мне это запретили делать (

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, про функцию `map`. Запутался.

Comment: @Иван, map - это еще одна функция которая обходит массив, зачастую более полезная. forEach - преобразует каждый элемент. map - преобразует каждый элемент и возвращает преобразованные элементы в виде нового массива.

Comment: @Иван, их можно с минимальными дописываниями заменять друг на друга, разница между ними в основном семантическая (когда результирующий массив нужен - map, когде не нужен - forEach). А еще .map короче и модней) Можно задать отдельный вопрос, я думаю вам быстро пояснят на примерах, в комментариях это неудобно

Answer (score 6):

Первое что приходит в голову - объединить однотипные условия как-то так:

```
// Перед циклом, чтобы не создавать этот объект в каждой итерации
let columnsList = [
    'id', 
    'email', 
    'FIO',
    'phone',
    'role'
];

// Немножко кода пропущено

// Внутри тела цикла
columnsList.forEach(columnName => {
    var tdEl = document.createElement('td');
        tdEl.innerHTML = data_parse[i][columnName];

        tagTrDataEmployee.append(tdEl);
});
```

На более сложные оптимизации я в 2 часа ночи не способен)
Могу еще сказать если таблица реально очень большая то быстрее склеивать строку, а потом уже делать из нее DOM элементы, но здесь - роли не играет.

Еще можно не хардкодить лист колонок а брать прям из объекта все что приехало:

```
let columnsList = Object.keys(data_parse[i]);
```

(Как верно заметил Qwertiy у Object.keys может вернуть ключи не в том порядке что у вас в шапке, и это надо иметь в виду)

**UPD:** посмотрел с утра внимательнее. Вы используете jQuery, что значительно упрощает описанную выше оптимизацию.
Можно написать что-то в духе `$('<div>test</div>')`, то есть скормить jQuery кусок html написанный в виде строки, и он разберет это сам. В результате кусок создающий строку можно записать совсем просто:

```
let rowString = `<tr>`;

columnsList.forEach(columnName => {
     rowString += `<td>${data_parse[i][columnName]}</td>`;
});

rowString +=`</tr>`;

let rowEl = $(rowString);
```

(На работоспособность я проверять поленился, но думаю идея понятна).
**Внимание:** как верно заметил Qwertiy что если данные которые Вы показываете вводятся юзером и не валидируется - есть шанс пропустить xss.
Но если так показываются какие-то заранее валидные данные, то можно и так.

Почему это имеет смысл? Дело в том, что операции с js строками сами - очень быстрые. Операции по изменению в DOM - **значительно** медленнее. Вызовы каких-то браузерных API за пределами js движка - в целом медленнее.

Да, обратите внимание что я использую в коде ES6-конструкции (=> - стрелочные функции, `` - шаблонные строки), но так как у вас уже есть let, я предположил что с этим проблем нет.

Comment: ``<td>${data_parse[i][columnName]}</td>`` - не надо так. А что если там html-теги окажутся? И jQuery не разворачивается в createElement. А у `Object.keys` может порядок с порядком столбцов не совпасть. Какие-то ты вредные советы даёшь... Хотя стоп, там и в оригинале html, странно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так так так, давайте по порядку. 
Про порядок Object.keys не подумал, согласен (писал в 2 часа ночи =)).  Про createElement я поленился смотреть, поэтому и написал "вероятно" =)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот про первый пункт хотелось бы поподробнее

Comment: Подставь данные из моего ответа и полюбуйся alert'ом ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, вот так согласен) Ну да, это потенциальная xss, но в некоторых случаях так можно разумеется)

Comment: еще один forEach, там где должен был быть map :)

Comment: @Grundy, здесь кмк принципиальной разницы нету птмшта конечный результат - не массив а строчка. Можно конечно вернуть массив и заджойнить его. Вообще мне хотелось бы посмотреть на Вашу версию =)

Comment: @Grundy если Вы про первый forEach, то да, можно вернуть массив и заппендить прямо его, я просто это писал очень сонным